# Can't transmate string through MariaDB connect/c Prepared Statement

Tags: c, mariadb

I'm using "MariaDB Connector/C" for my homework, but I got a problem: I always get an empty string when I pass in a string parameter, the db table is:

```
MariaDB none@(none):test> SELECT * FROM t3
```

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | abc |
| 1 | bcd |
| 2 | af |

```txt
3 rows in set
Time: 0.010s
```

```
MariaDB none@(none):test> DESC t3
```

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | int(11) | NO | PRI |  |  |
| b | char(10) | YES |  |  |  |

```txt
2 rows in set
Time: 0.011s
```

And the code I use to test:

```c
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    MYSQL *mysql;
    mysql = mysql_init(NULL);
    if (!mysql_real_connect(mysql,NULL , "none", "linux", "test", 0,"/tmp/mariadb.sock",0)){
        printf( "Error connecting to database: %s",mysql_error(mysql));
    } else
        printf("Connected...\n");
    if(mysql_real_query(mysql,"SET CHARACTER SET utf8",(unsigned int)sizeof("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"))){
        printf("Failed to set Encode!\n");
    }


    char query_stmt_2[]="select * from t3 where b=?";
    MYSQL_STMT *stmt2 = mysql_stmt_init(mysql);
    if(mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt2, query_stmt_2, -1))
    {
        printf("STMT2 prepare failed.\n");
    }
    MYSQL_BIND instr_bind;
    char instr[50]="abc";
    my_bool in_is_null = 0;
    my_bool in_error = 0;
    instr_bind.buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    instr_bind.buffer = &instr[0];
    char in_ind = STMT_INDICATOR_NTS;
    instr_bind.u.indicator = &in_ind;
    unsigned long instr_len=sizeof(instr);
    // instr_bind.length = &instr_len;
    // instr_bind.buffer_length=instr_len;
    instr_bind.is_null = &in_is_null;
    instr_bind.error = &in_error;


    MYSQL_BIND out_bind[2];
    memset(out_bind, 0, sizeof(out_bind));
    int out_int[2];
    char outstr[50];
    my_bool out_int_is_null[2]={0,0};
    my_bool out_int_error[2]={0,0};
    unsigned long out_int_length[2]={0,0};
    out_bind[0].buffer = out_int+0;
    out_bind[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_LONG;
    out_bind[0].is_null = out_int_is_null+0;
    out_bind[0].error = out_int_error+0;
    out_bind[0].length = out_int_length+0;

    out_bind[1].buffer = outstr;
    out_bind[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    out_bind[1].buffer_length = 50;
    out_bind[1].is_null = out_int_is_null+1;
    out_bind[1].error = out_int_error+1;
    out_bind[1].length = out_int_length+1;

    if(mysql_stmt_bind_param(stmt2, &instr_bind) ||
    mysql_stmt_bind_result(stmt2, out_bind)){
        printf("Bind error\n");
    }

    if(mysql_stmt_execute(stmt2))
    {
        printf("Exec error: %s",mysql_stmt_error(stmt2));
    }

    if(mysql_stmt_store_result(stmt2)){
        printf("Store result error!\n");
        printf("%s\n",mysql_stmt_error(stmt2));
    }
    while(!mysql_stmt_fetch(stmt2))
    {
        printf("%d\t%s\n", out_int[0], outstr);
    }
    mysql_stmt_close(stmt2);
end:
    mysql_close(mysql);

}
```

I only got an empty result:

```txt
❯ ./Exec/test/stmt_test
Connected...
```

I have been in trouble with this for two days, and tomorrow is the deadline, I'm very anxious. Can you help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to step through the code statement by statement, what happens?

Comment: In addition, when i use "INSERT" method, all string become empty but INT value is corrected inserted.

Comment: Are you really sure about using `sizeof` in `unsigned long instr_len=sizeof(instr);`? Shouldn't it be `strlen(instr)` instead?

Comment: Thanks for reply. "instr" is a  stack variable, sizeof will give a correct buffer size, and i don't use the length below.

Comment: I have debugged using gdb, and the pointer(MYSQL_BIND->buffer) always pointer to the string correctly, i haven't read the source code about connect/c, so i don't no what it's doing to my data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) General**

- Avoid "it was hard to write, so it should be hard to read" code
- add variable declarations at the beginning of the function, not in the middle of code (Wdeclaration-after-statement)
- don't use c++ comments in C
- set character set with api function mysql_set_character_set()
- write proper error handling, including mysql_error/mysql_stmt_error results and don't continue executing subsequent code after error.
- always initialize MYSQL_BIND

**2) input bind buffer**

- u.indicator is used for bulk operations and doesn't make sense here
- bind.is_null is not required, since you specified a valid buffer address
- buffer_length is not set (in comments)

**3) Output bind buffer**

- Always bind output parameters after mysql_stmt_execute(), since mysql_stmt_prepare can't always determine the number of parameters, e.g. when calling a stored procedure: In this case mysql_stmt_bind_param will return an error.
- binding an error indicator doesn't make much sense without setting MYSQL_REPORT_DATA_TRUNCATION (mysql_optionsv)

For some examples how to deal with prepared statements check the file  ps.c of [MariaDB Connector/C unit tests](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/tree/3.3/unittest/libmariadb)